# datetime64[ns] to Timestamp String in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I haver a Series:

```
>>> ser = pd.Series(['2008-08-05 18:36:48','2008-08-01 14:45:37','2008-09-08 14:03:52'],index=[0,1,2],dtype='datetime64[ns]')

>>> ser

0   2008-08-05 18:36:48

1   2008-08-01 14:45:37

2   2008-09-08 14:03:52

dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And the ser[0] and ser[0:1]

```
>>> ser[0]
Timestamp('2008-08-05 18:36:48')
>>>ser[0:2]
0   2008-08-05 18:36:48
1   2008-08-01 14:45:37
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The values of ser are:

```
ser.values
array(['2008-08-06T02:36:48.000000000+0800',
   '2008-08-01T22:45:37.000000000+0800',
   '2008-09-08T22:03:52.000000000+0800'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

The problem is that , for example, the time is **'2008-08-06T02:36:48.000000000+0800'** and not is **'2008-08-05 18:36:48'**

I need import the values of ser into Database like this:
**['2008-08-05 18:36:48','2008-08-01 14:45:37','2008-09-08 14:03:52']**

How can I get the list of timestamp, not the '2008-08-06T02:36:48.000000000+0800'?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to construct `pd.DatetimeIndex` and call `to_native_types()`

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(ser).to_native_types()

array(['2008-08-05 18:36:48', '2008-08-01 14:45:37', '2008-09-08 14:03:52'], dtype=object)
```

Or just manipulate on numpy array (set resolution to `s` instead of `ns` and then convert to string):

```
ser.values.astype('<M8[s]').astype(str)

array(['2008-08-05T18:36:48Z', '2008-08-01T14:45:37Z', '2008-09-08T14:03:52Z'], 
      dtype='<U38')
```

Comment: Hi Jianxun li, i have another question, print ser
['2008-08-05 18:36:48' '2008-08-01 14:45:37' '2008-09-08 14:03:52']
>>> ser
array(['2008-08-05 18:36:48', '2008-08-01 14:45:37', '2008-09-08 14:03:52'], dtype=object). How can I get the string like this: string=2008-08-05 18:36:48,2008-08-01 14:45:37,2008-09-08 14:03:52